# Is it right approach to fix problem of BST?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have to check is Binary tree balanced and I am pretty sure my solution should work.
[image]

```
import sys
class Solution:
    def isBalanced(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        cache = {
            max:-sys.maxsize, #min possible number
            min:sys.maxsize   #max possible number
        }
        self.checkBalanced(root, cache, 0)
        return cache[max] - cache[min] <= 1

    def checkBalanced(self,node, cache, depth):
        if node is None:
            if depth < cache[min]:
                cache[min] = depth
            if depth > cache[max]:
                cache[max] = depth
        else:
            self.checkBalanced(node.left, cache, depth+1)
            self.checkBalanced(node.right, cache, depth+1)
```

But in this case I have an error
[image]

Here is link for question on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree

Comment: Thanks for the update. But you should really post the error as text, not as an image. See also https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a definition from the link that you provided:

> For this problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as: a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differ by more than 1.

For given "bad" input your code calculates cache[max] = 5, cache[min] = 3, so it returns false. However, if we consider root, its left subtree has depth 4 and right subtree has depth 3, so this satisfies the definition.

[image]

You should find depths of left and right subtrees for each root, however your code calculates depth (your `cache[max]`) and length of shortest path to any leaf of subtree (your `cache[min]`).

I hope you will easily fix your code after these clarifications.